# jQuery get JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to pull in the total shares from a number of pages and have them displayed on my home page. I'm using addthis for the share buttons. I found a way to pull in the required info using JSON [here](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/916750-total-shares).

Since I have multiple urls I'm storing them in an array, then cycling through and calling each one. Here's my code...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var shareCountArray = [ "url1",  //Array to put all url's to get share total
                     "url2"]  
    shareCountArray.forEach( function(shareUrl) { 
        var url = "//api-public.addthis.com/url/shares.json?url=http%3A%2F%2F"+ shareUrl +"?callback=?";
        jQuery.getJSON(url, function(json) {                                            
            alert(json.shares);
        }); 
    });
});
```

It's throwing up the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : ". I thought this may have been because I included `?callback=?` but when I remove that the console throws up errors because they're different origins.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you  missing a semi-colon after `"url2"]`?

Comment: `shareUrl` is not the same as `url` ?

Comment: And, javascript has a same origin policy.

Comment: You're missing a `;` when you're closing off `shareCountArray.forEach( function(shareUrl)`

Can you post the error you're getting for the different origins?

Comment: What are the actual URLs?

Comment: @Mörre Sorry, I edited the format. @adeneo `shareUrl` is the value pulled from the array, `url` is the full url using the api with the `shareUrl` stored inside. @Matt The actual url's havent been made yet but they will be just basic pages stored on the current site such as mysite.com/folder/page1.php

Comment: `api-public.addthis.com` does not allow cross origin calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you include `callback=?` then jQuery thinks the response is JSONP. JSONP is nothing else than including a JavaScript file. I.e. the response you receive is interpreted as JavaScript. That also means that if the server returns anything else than valid JavaScript, you will get an error. JSON on its own is not valid JS syntax, that's why you get the that error (you can verify that easily by putting `{"foo": 42}` in the console).

> when I remove that the console throws up errors because they're different origins.

JSONP as well as CORS have to be supported by the server. You can't make an Ajax or JSONP request to the server if it doesn't. See [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3076414/218196) for alternatives.

**But** it actually looks like [the service does support JSONP](http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381267-addthis-web-service-framework#response_formats):

> When calling services that support html responses, you may omit the .html extension. Optionally, you can use json mode and pass callback=function to specify a jsonp callback wrapper. Content-Type headers are set on responses as appropriate.

Looking at your URL, it is malformed. You should use `&callback=?` instead of `?callback=?`. Multiple request parameters in a URL are separated by `&`. `?` only indicates the *beginning* of the query string. E.g.

```
http://example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

Learn more about URLs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url

Comment: Thank you @Felix replacing it with `&callback=?` fixed it.